# Solved Now: Limiting Permutations Python Solution

Tags: python, recursion, combinatorics

The solution was made by commenters: saving the post incase it helps anyone else out.

I am currently attempting to write a python script to fill a useable matrix that would include all possible permutations of five numbers that add to 100, with these five numbers also only being multiples of five, excluding zeros ie the end permutations are (5,5,5,5,80) and (80,5,5,5,5). So far I have a simple script that can run to find this with all integers (ie 1,1,1,1,96 as a solution), however, this is not including the multiple of five limitation, so the solution is practically unsolvable (code will not run in a reasonable timeframe) on my slow computer with the ~4.6 million solutions available. Any recommendations on how to proceed would be extremely valuable: I am a synthetic chemist trying my best and not a programmer so please be patient :)

Script:

```
 def sum_k(n, k):
    if n == 1:
        yield (k,)
    else:
        for x in range(1, k):
            for i in sum_k(n - 1, k - x):
                yield (x,) + i


print(list(sum_k(5, 100)))
```

Comment: Also, those are not permutations but combinations.

Comment: Can't you just change the loop to `for x in range(5, k, 5):`? Result seems right to me (after superficial check) and fast enough for your example.

Comment: @KellyBundy I guess "combinations" is not entirely correct either, since e.g. (1,1,2) and (1,2,1) would be the same combination, but then for permutations it would include both (1,1,2) and (1,1,2), so I guess is something between the two...

Comment: yes! this worked. thank you so much.

Comment: yes, I found my typo and it runs great now. thank you both a ton! saved me hours of scratching my head haha.

Comment: @tobias_k We can [use](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY4xDsIwDEX3nMKjowapSFTiLoghjRKI1MSR6w49CmLpAnfiNgRKBzz8wfrv692fZZYr5WV5TBJ2x9ctMCWI4lmIhhFiKsQCjlIfs5VIeVTfChXPVoi3xjj1ShWOWfAkUxk8Jluwfg24Bvdta7QBrNk4rRWsFyrvIOa_fWSbLx47Ax8Kusod9Fmvgj_PzfcN) combinations, though :-)

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix this would be to change your loop to use a [3-parameter `range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) including the `step` parameter, i.e. `range(5, k, 5)`, starting from `5` and incrementing in steps of 5. With this, your code seems to work fine, quickly yielding the expected results.

You might also make this another parameter (remember to also pass it to the recursive call), and change the inner nested loop to `yield from` a generator.

```
def sum_k(n, k, m=1):
    if n == 1:
        yield (k,)
    else:
        yield from ((x,) + i for x in range(m, k, m) for i in sum_k(n-1, k-x, m))

for x in sum_k(5, 100, 5):
    print(x)
```